# Interpretation of 'most likely' in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose we toss a coin $4$ times, there are a total of $16$ possible outcomes.

Let us consider the probabilities of these outcomes, using the binomial distribution.

The probability of getting equal heads and tails is $6/16$. This is the most likely outcome.

The probability of getting $1$ or $3$ heads is $4/16$.

Similarly, the probability of getting $4$ or $0$ heads is $1/16$.

My question is about what these numbers truly represent. Say I toss a coin 4 times - this is my experiment. Does this mean that I'm most likely to get an equal number of heads and tails in the experiment? The outcome with equal heads and tails have the highest probability among other outcomes. However some people argue, that the other outcomes have a higher combined probability, so, they should be more likely. I'm unable to wrap my head around this logic.

Does it mean, that if I carry out this experiment many times, $6/16$ of the total experiments would give us an equal number of head and tails ? Is this the correct interpretation instead ?

I've shown that getting equal heads and tails has the highest probability and so it is the most likely among other outcomes. However, what does most likely truly mean ? Does it mean, in a single experiment, we are most likely to obtain this value. Or does it mean, in many many experiments, this outcome shows up the most. Which one of these interpretations is correct ?

Comment: Getting equal heads and tails is called an **event** (not an outcome). There are 16 outcomes $\{(HHHH), ..., (TTTT)\}$ and the event $A$ of getting equal heads and tails is the set of outcomes $$A=\{(HHTT), (HTHT), (THHT), (THTH), (TTHH), (HTTH)\}$$

Comment: The standard assumption for coins is that all 16 outcomes of the sample space are equally likely (meaning each has a probability mass of $1/16$).  An **event** is a subset of the sample space.

Comment: @Michael okay, but which event is most likely to occur? And what does most likely mean really? In this example, the subset of event equal head equal tail is larger than the subset of the event of 3 heads 1 tails, as there are less number of ways, that can happen. Does this mean, event of equal heads and tails is more likely than event of three heads and a tail for example ?

Comment: If you ask about "most likely" you should specify the set of options under consideration.  If we consider all possible events, the most likely event is the event equal to the entire sample space $S$, since $P[S]=1$.  But if you consider a collection of only 5 possible events, the one that is "most likely" is the one with highest probability.  And of course there might be ties for most likely.

Comment: @Michael yes, but I seem to hit a contradiction here. Suppose there are $5$ events, getting $0-4$ heads in 4 tosses. Out of these, the event with an equal number of heads and tails is the most probable, as it has a larger sample space of outcomes than the rest of the events. So, one can say, that getting equal heads is most probable. However, imagine now there are two events - getting equal heads and tails , and not getting equal heads and tails. Now the second event has a larger sample space, than the first one, and should now be considered more probable.

Comment: Correct.  There is no contradiction because in the two different questions you are considering different options as your events.  The first question compares the 5 events $A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$.  The second question compares the two events $A_2$ and $A_2^c$.

Comment: @Michael in the first case, we saw that event of two heads and two tails is more likely than any other event. In the second case, we saw that getting two heads and tails is less likely than not getting them. Since, we are essentially describing the same situation, our two approaches give us contradictory results. Getting equal heads and tails is more probable than other events, but less probable than the combination of other events.

Comment: @Michael aren't the two different questions describing the same exact phenomenon. Our final outcome should not depend on how we describe the events, shouldn't it ?

Comment: You are just noticing that $P[A_2]\geq P[A_i]$ for all $i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, but $$P[A_2]<P[A_2^c]=P[A_0]+P[A_1]+P[A_3]+P[A_4]$$ Also, the sample space never changes, it is always the same 16 outcomes.  We can ask questions about different events (subsets) of this sample space.

Comment: @Michael yes, this is exactly what I'm noticing, however, I'm not sure how to interpret this. $A_2$ is more likely than $A_i$. However, $A_2$ is less likely than $A_2^c$. This is rather contradictory to me. It says, getting two heads out of four is more likely than all other events, but less likely than not getting two heads out of four. If this is true, then we should expect unequal heads or tails. However, each of unequal heads or tails is less likely than equal heads and tails. If this is true, then what should really be our expected outcome ? This seems somewhat paradoxical to me.

Comment: "most likely" is just a way to refer to the mode (or modes) of a distribution. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics))

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay It is easy to find 5 numbers with the property that one of the numbers is strictly larger than the other 4, but not as large as the sum of all the other 4.